# MAC OSX Routes Table

Tags: networking, macos, vpn, routing, static-routes

If I add a route such as `route -n add 10.10.10.10 10.255.255.255` i can reach the server under 10.10.10.10, BUT if i add a route `route -n add 10.0.0.0/24 10.255.255.255` and remove the other, i can't reach any server under the 10.xxx.xxx.xxx ip range... what command should i use to tell my OS to use the gateway `10.255.255.255` to any traffic that resolves to the `10.anything`?

**EDIT 1**
10.0.0.0/8 also didn't work
10.10.0.0/16 also didn't work

Comment: Is it immediately after you add the command? Because this command is only active after issuing it and before the next reboot.

Comment: And looking at the above I think you also got the subnet wrong: /24 = 255.255.255.0 so you are adding route to 10.0.0.X

Comment: @TomEus /8 didn't work either... and yes, no reboots...

Comment: 10.255.255.255 would be the broadcast address for 10.0.0.0/8 network. You should change your gateway to 10.255.255.254/8, or if you want to use /24 use 10.0.0.254.

Comment: @DrZoo my bad on that one, i meant like a specific-complete IP addr on the 10.X net... like 10.1.1.1

Comment: The command you need is `route -n add 10.0.0.0/8 10.255.255.254`, But like I said, your gateway address needs to be 10.255.255.254, not 10.255.255.255.